# How to catch different events from dom elements (div/img/input) and how to interact(get/set attributes,styles,classes) with them with react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

for example we have this button
and this div

```
<button onClick={test_func}>
</button>
<div class="js_test">
</div>
```

in jquery we do so !

```
$(document).on('click', '.js_test', fu
    //code
});
$(document).on('EVENT_TYPE', 'ELEMENT_DOM', function(evt) {});

$('ELEMENT_DOM').css();
$('ELEMENT_DOM').attr();
$('ELEMENT_DOM').addClass();
```

in  js you can catch all events by class or id

.js_test

so how is it like in React.js

```
test_func() {
    //inside here i need to do something with div .js_test 
    // to set text, add new class, set new css style like color: 'red' for example
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the event in the function, and use e.target (.nextElementSibling to target the div close to the button) Or you can use the useRef hook, and use ref.current

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRef } from "react"

function Teste(){
    const ref = useRef();
    const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

    function AlterWithEDotTarget(e){
        e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "WAS ALTERED!"
    }

    function AlterWithUseRef(){
        ref.current.innerHTML  = "WAS ALTERED!";
    }

    function ToggleDarkMode() {
        setDarkMode(!darkMode)
    }

    return (<>
                <button onClick={AlterWithEDotTarget}>Alter With e.target</button>
                <div>Will be altered with e.target {darkMode ? "DarkMode ON" : ""}</div>

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <button onClick={AlterWithUseRef}>Alter With useRef</button>
                <div ref={ref}>Will be altered with useRef {darkMode ? "DarkMode ON" : ""}</div>

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <button onClick={ToggleDarkMode}>Toggle Dark Mode</button>
            </>)

}

export default Teste
```

**EDIT**

In react things are different than jQuery, i added an example targeting multiple elements, you do it using state, and binding the state to the elements, and when the state changes, the elements change as well

Comment: thank you so much Paulo...i do actually have another question which is there any way in react like is it possible in jquery... to catch multiple events in once like i mentioned above in the code? Paulo?

Comment: you're a life saver man so much love !

Comment: Your welcome! If you could mark as accepted and vote up, i would really appreciate :))